# Getting Null Pointer Exception when trying to get the value from global variable

Tags: java

This is the Class which stores the global variables

```
public class GlobalVariables extends Application {
private String userToken;
private String userId;
private String userName;

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public String getUserToken() {
    return userToken;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public void setUserToken(String userToken) {
    this.userToken = userToken;
}

}
```

Now i am setting the values in login class

```
                GlobalVariables newObj = new GlobalVariables();

                newObj.setUserId(user_values.getString("id"));

                newObj.setUserName(user_values.getString("name"));

                System.out.println(newObj.getUserId());
```

I am getting that value in systemout ,,, But when i try to fetch the value from another class i am getting Null pointer Exception

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.timetable);
        TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testing);
        GlobalVariables newObj = new GlobalVariables();
        System.out.println( newObj.getUserId());


    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `new` keyword?? it will clear all your data..

try this..

   `GlobalVariables newObj;
    System.out.println( newObj.getUserId());`

Comment: Take a look at [Using Application Class in Android](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/androids-application-class/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead Of using

```
`GlobalVariables newObj = new GlobalVariables();
    System.out.println( newObj.getUserId());`
```

use

`System.out.println((GlobalVariables) getApplication()).getUserId());`

Comment: I tried that ,,, its giving the same error,,, When storing also shud i do the same

Answer (score 0):

You are instating the class:

```
GlobalVariables newObj = new GlobalVariables();
```

so it's normal you have null pointer exception when in the next line you do:

```
 System.out.println( newObj.getUserId());
```

I recomend you to use Singleton Pattern or a Static Class to store Global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to getting Application class variable so,Change this

```
 GlobalVariables newObj = new GlobalVariables();
        System.out.println( newObj.getUserId());
```

to

```
 GlobalVariables newObj = (GlobalVariables) getApplication();
        System.out.println(newObj.getUserId());
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the initialization of the newObj.UseId property.
Anyway, if you wish to avoid Nullpointer exception try this:

```
public String getUserId() {
return userId==null?String.Empty:userId;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `initialization` of data, put a `constructor`

```
public GlobalVariables() {
    super();
    userToken = "";
    userId = "";
    userName = "";
}
```

Here you care creating a ne object

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.timetable);
    TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testing);
    GlobalVariables newObj = new GlobalVariables();//do not initilize 
    System.out.println( newObj.getUserId());//must get null pointer exception
}
```

So always put constructor if you have fields.